# Facebook publication from app to page wall invisible to others

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I have a big problem, I try to publish a post from an Facebook app to a Facebook page wall.

I used this function to do so :

```
function Post_facebook($message){ 

    include_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

    $app_config = array(
        'appId' => '*********',
        'secret' => '************');

    $page_config = array(
        'access_token' => '********',
        'page_id' => '*********');

    $facebook = new Facebook($app_config);

    $params = array(
       'access_token' => $page_config['access_token'],
       'message' => $message);

    $post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_config['page_id'].'/feed','post',$params);
}
```

Everything seems to be ok, but only I can see the posts.
When I'm on the wall everything seems normal, I see posts from the app. But if someone else goes on the wall, he won't be able to. Publication are set to 'Public' on privacy settings so I can't see why it's not working.

If I go to post URL (`https://www.facebook.com/*****/posts/*****`) from another account it says : *page doesn't exist....*

Comment: Out of interest is the application on facebook set to development or live? If its not published as live then only users credited as being developers of the app are able to see those posts.

Comment: It is set to live. I can post directly from the wall and everything is fine. Only post from the app are not visible to everyone...
Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable sandbox-mode from your Facebook app's settings